# Javascript/Jquery Excel File Name

Tags: javascript, excel

I refer below example

http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/537/

If I click to "Export to Excel" it downloads file as excel however file name always **"Download.xls"** in my language.

How can I change specific **Download.xls to "MyFile.xls"** ?

**Javascript Code:**

```
    var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
          , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
          , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); }
          , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }); }
        return function (table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        }
    })()
```

I changed worksheet and names however it did not work for me. How can I change downloaded file name ?

Comment: Any help please i really can not do this bymyself thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just place the link any where in your page

anchor tag  `id="exprotData"`  `style="display:none;"`  closing of anchor tag

and change your export function by using this method

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name, filename) {
        table = tableId;
        name = "Report";
        filename = "Report.xls";
        if (table != "") {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            $(table).find(':not(:visible)').remove();
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
          document.getElementById("exprotData").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
          document.getElementById("exprotData").download = filename;
          document.getElementById("exprotData").click();
        }
        else {
            alert('No Record Found.');
        }
    }
    tableId = '';
})()
```

You can pass these three parameters : table, name, filename globally according to your needs.

Comment: @Richard please check this code. I hope it will work for youl

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me please try it.

```
  var tableToExcel = (function () {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function (table, name, filename) {
                table = document.getElementById(table);
                name = "Report";
                filename = "Report.xls";
                if (table != "") {
                    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                    $(table).find(':not(:visible)').remove();
                    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                    document.getElementById("exprotData").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                    document.getElementById("exprotData").download = filename;
                    document.getElementById("exprotData").click();
                }
                else {
                    alert('No Record Found.');
                }
            }
            tableId = '';
        })()
```